# pyqt and VTK : problem to connect slider to vtk object

Tags: python, pyqt, vtk

I'm dealing with some issues, using vtk in PyQt5. The problem is that I have a vtk sphere with an initial radius value and some sliders to connect to the sphere dans QLCD Numbers. Indeed, what I want is to have one of the sliders set at 128 at first dans when the user slide to change the value, this value will be displayed in the QLCDNumber and the current value of the slider will be taken to change the Radius of the VTK Sphere.

Here's my code :

```
    import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QSlider, QLCDNumber
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QCheckBox, QGridLayout, QGroupBox,
                             QMenu, QPushButton, QRadioButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget, QSlider,QLineEdit,QLabel)
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5 import *
import vtk
from vtk.qt.QVTKRenderWindowInteractor import QVTKRenderWindowInteractor
from PyQt5 import Qt

def window():

   source = vtk.vtkSphereSource()
   source.SetCenter(0, 0, 0)
   source.SetRadius(5.0)

   app = QApplication(sys.argv)
   win = QWidget()

   Display_1 = QLCDNumber(3)
   Display_2 = QLCDNumber(3)
   Display_3 = QLCDNumber(3)

   Display_1.setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber.Flat)
   Display_2.setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber.Flat)
   Display_3.setSegmentStyle(QLCDNumber.Flat)

   Display_1.display(128)
   Display_2.display(128)
   Display_3.display(128)

   Slider_1 = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
   Slider_1.setMinimum(0)
   Slider_1.setMaximum(255)
   Slider_1.setValue(128)
   Slider_1.valueChanged.connect(Display_1.display)
   Slider_1.valueChanged.connect(changevalue(Slider_1,source))

   Slider_2 = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
   Slider_2.setMinimum(0)
   Slider_2.setMaximum(255)
   Slider_2.setValue(128)
   Slider_2.valueChanged.connect(Display_2.display)


   Slider_3 = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
   Slider_3.setMinimum(0)
   Slider_3.setMaximum(255)
   Slider_3.setValue(128)
   Slider_3.valueChanged.connect(Display_3.display)

   label_1 = QLabel("Label_1")
   label_1.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

   label_2 = QLabel("Label_2")
   label_2.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

   label_3 = QLabel("Label_3")
   label_3.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)  

   vbox = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()


   vbox.addWidget(label_1)
   vbox.addWidget(Display_1)
   vbox.addWidget(Slider_1)

   vbox.addWidget(label_2)
   vbox.addWidget(Display_2)
   vbox.addWidget(Slider_2)

   vbox.addWidget(label_3)
   vbox.addWidget(Display_3)
   vbox.addWidget(Slider_3)

   vbox.addStretch()






   hbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()

   frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
   frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
   frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel) # Application de la forme
   frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised) # application d'une ombre
   frame.setObjectName("frame") # Appellation du cadre

   #b3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button3")
   #b4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton("Button4")
   hbox.addWidget(frame)
   hbox.addStretch()
   #hbox.addWidget(b4)

   vbox.addStretch()
   hbox.addLayout(vbox)
   win.setLayout(hbox)



   vtkWidget = QVTKRenderWindowInteractor(frame)
   vl = Qt.QVBoxLayout()
   vl.addWidget(vtkWidget)

   ren = vtk.vtkRenderer()
   vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().AddRenderer(ren)
   iren = vtkWidget.GetRenderWindow().GetInteractor()



  # Create a mapper
   mapper = vtk.vtkPolyDataMapper()
   mapper.SetInputConnection(source.GetOutputPort())

  # Create an actor
   actor = vtk.vtkActor()
   actor.SetMapper(mapper)

   ren.AddActor(actor)
   ren.ResetCamera()
   frame.setLayout(vl)
   #setCentralWidget(self.frame)
   #show()
   iren.Initialize()
   iren.Start()

   win.setWindowTitle("PyQt")
   win.resize(743, 430)
   win.show()
   sys.exit(app.exec_())

def changevalue(slider,source):
   value  = slider.value()
   source.SetRadius(int(value))


if __name__ == '__main__':
   window()
```

When I try to use the code the python returns me the following error : "File "window.py", line 38, in window
    Slider_1.valueChanged.connect(changevalue(Slider_1,source))
TypeError: argument 1 has unexpected type 'NoneType'"

Any idea ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: change to `Slider_1.valueChanged.connec(source.SetRadius)`

Comment: Thanks it's working, but it needs to click on the scene to have the sphere radius updated. I tried .Update() on iron but it doesn't work

Comment: You say: *it's working*, so it makes me think that your current question is solved, which does not imply that you have another problem.

Comment: Actually I'm looking for solutions that makes me able to update the scene automatically without clicking on it, sorry if I wasn't clear enough on that point

Comment: Read the title of your question: **problem to connect slider to vtk object**, it is very clear and it is already solved. If you have another problem (maybe you thought it was solved with this question) then publish another post with the direct question similar to: *update the scene without clicking on it*

Comment: Fine ! I'll do it, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

The `connect` method in PyQt is expecting a function object.  Instead, you are calling a function:

`changevalue(Slider_1,source)`

The function `changevalue` doesn't return anything.  In other words, it returns `None`.

So, when you call the line:

`Slider_1.valueChanged.connect(changevalue(Slider_1,source))`

what you are really doing is calling `connect` with `None` as the argument becuase this is what your function call to `changevalue` is returning.  Instead, you need to pass it the function `changevalue`, but since you need to call that function with arguments, you'll need to do something like this:

```
...
Slider_1 = QSlider(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
   Slider_1.setMinimum(0)
   Slider_1.setMaximum(255)
   Slider_1.setValue(128)
   def handler():
       changevalue(Slider_1, source)
   Slider_1.valueChanged.connect(Display_1.display)
   Slider_1.valueChanged.connect(handler)
...
```

I ran your code with this modification and the sphere displays.  However, there is one other issue and that is that when you move the sliders, your sphere doesn't update.  In order to get the VTK renderer to update, you'll need to figure out how to call `iren.reinitialize()` in your `changevalue` handler, or something to this effect.  The reinitialize call will cause the render window to update in response to the slider movement.

Comment: Thanks for your help ! I've been able to change the radius, but the scene only updates when i click on it. I tried iron.reinitialize() but it seems that renderers have no method reinitialize. Looking for solutions

Comment: Actually, it is `iren.ReInitialize()` (notice the capitalization).  I had it incorrect in my response.  The documentation (albeit not great) for the `VTKRenderWindowInteractor` is here: https://www.vtk.org/doc/release/7.1/html/classvtkRenderWindowInteractor.html

Comment: I use reintialize on the render window interactor whenever I want to force it to update following a programmatic (non-interactive) change.  In your case, since the slider is a part of the rest of your application and not interaction within the render window interactor itself, you'll need to call reinitialize to force it to update.

Comment: Indeed, it works ! Thanks a lot !